# Entity Framework - Data Annotations Range Validator throws exception instead of displaying error message

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, data-annotations

I'm trying to create a form about vendor registration in a company. One of the field required is Number of Workers.

I added Range validator in Form Model as below.

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Form Number is required!")]
public int FormNo { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please fill in the Number of Workers field!")]
[Range(0, 20, ErrorMessage = "Please enter positive number only!")]
public int NWorkers { get; set; }
```

Every time the input is outside the range, it throws exception instead of displaying the ErrorMessage.

```
System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException: 'Validation
failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property
for more details.'
```

If the input is within the range, it works fine.

Here is my controller

```
public class FormController : Controller {
    private AppDbContext db = new AppDbContext();

    // GET: Form
    public ActionResult Index() {
        return View(db.Forms.ToList());
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create() {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Form form) {
        form.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;
        form.UpdatedAt = DateTime.Now;

        db.Forms.Add(form);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("index", "form");
    }
}
```

Here is my view

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="@Url.Action("create", "form")" method="post">
   @if (!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid) {
      <div class="alert alert-danger">
         @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "")
      </div>
   }

   <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="FormNo">Form Number</label>
      <div class="col-md-3">
         @Html.TextBox("FormNo", null, new { @class = "form-control required", @required = "true" })
      </div>
      <span class="col-md-3 pull-right note">Note : * is required</span>
   </div>

   <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="NWorkers">Number of Workers</label>
      <div class="col-md-3 required">
         @Html.TextBox("NWorkers", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
         <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control" id="NWorkers" name="NWorkers" value="0" /> -->
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="box-footer">
      <div class="col-md-offset-3">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            <i class="fa fa-btn fa-floppy-o"></i> Save
         </button>
         <a onclick="history.back();" class="btn btn-warning">
            <i class="fa fa-reply"></i> Cancel
         </a>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

**Edit**

[image: Error Details]

StackTrace

> "   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()\r\n
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()\r\n
>   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()\r\n   at
>   HSE.Controllers.FormController.Create(Form form) in
>   C:\Users\PC17A196\source\repos\HSE\HSE\Controllers\FormController.cs:line
>   28\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )\r\n
>   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()"    string

Comment: Your validation attribute looks fine, it may throw exception because of other issues. Can you provide exception details when `DbEntityValidationException` occurs (including stack trace)? Also note that you should use data validation annotations in viewmodel, not data model.

Comment: In your POST method you should be checking of `ModelState` is valid, and if not return the view - `if (!ModelState.IsValid) { return view(form); }`, and you add `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` for each property to display the errors

Comment: And why do you have a textbox for `FormNo` - that is the PK and cannot be editable

Comment: Also you should use combination of `@Html.TextBoxFor()` and `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` for every properties and avoid direct assignment to `FormNo` as primary key - the primary key should be processed in controller, not by user input.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, The FormNo field will be generated automatically by the controller based on the month and year. But since this is only an example, I decided to just enter it manually to make things easier.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, Thanks for the advice, I have added the Exception Details and Stack Trace.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, your solution solve my problem! It turns out I have to check the ModelState in my POST method controller and add @Html.ValidationMessageFor() in my view. Thanks!